# How to upsert multiple sObjects in a single DML where some have external ids as a matching field?

Tags: apex

I have a rest `@RestResource` class that has a post method which needs to upsert an Invoice on an external Id, and update the associated Acct. In my existing code, I have 2 dml statements below. Is there an optimization to put these into a single DML?

```
upsert invoice quickBooksId;
upsert acct;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot upsert more than one SObjectType in a single statement. It is not supported behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an external ID the way you have, you probably cannot combine those DML statements, since the system would have no way of knowing which type the field specified applies to.  In addition, while you can create a `List<sObject>` and put multiple types of sObjects in it to pass to one `update` or `insert` call, you are not allowed to `upsert` multiple types of sObjects in the same call.